# what is the difference between time_base and fps in x264 and ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264

there is codec parameters `time_base` and `fps` in x264, we actually can infer `fps` if we have `time_base`, so why x264 provide an extra parameter `fps`? It really confuses me, and it seems that `fps` doesn't work if I set both of them. also, ffmpeg encoder context has these two parameters

```
typedef struct x264_param_t
{
    uint32_t i_fps_num;
    uint32_t i_fps_den;
    uint32_t i_timebase_num;    /* Timebase numerator */
    uint32_t i_timebase_den;    /* Timebase denominator */
} rc;
```